# Python renaming an aggregated column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This should be easy but for some reason, I don't understand why it won't work. I have created a new dataframe by aggregating column data but I can't rename the new columns.

This is the code I used to generate columns

```
df10pctSum = df10pct.groupby('table_name').agg({'missing_index_impact':['sum','count']}).reset_index()
```

These are my two attempts to try and rename the sum column both attempts don't fail but neither of them rename the column

```
df10pctSum = df10pctSum.rename(columns={'(missing_index_impact, sum)':'MissingSum'})
df10pctSum = df10pctSum.rename(columns={'missing_index_impact, sum':'MissingSum'})
```

A `df10pctSum.info()` shows this

```
 #   Column                         Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                         --------------  -----  
 0   (table_name, )                 37 non-null     object 
 1   (missing_index_impact, sum)    37 non-null     float64
 2   (missing_index_impact, count)  37 non-null     int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 1016.0+ bytes
```

I would like to rename all of them but I can't even rename one. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a minimal reproducible example. The code you posted is not sufficient to describe what you're doing, as it has missing definitions, for example, as `df10pct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pass tuples or use `pd.NamedAgg` to give custom names to aggregated columns.

- [From **`Named Aggregation`** Docs(emphasis mine)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

  > The values are tuples whose **first element is the column to select and the second element is the aggregation to apply** to that column. pandas provides the pandas.NamedAgg namedtuple with the fields `['column', 'aggfunc']` to make it clearer what the arguments are.

```
df10pct.groupby('table_name').agg(
    Missingsum=("missing_index_impact", "sum"),
    Missingcount=("missing_index_impact", "count"),
)

# or

df10pct.groupby('table_name').agg(
    Missingsum=pd.NamedAgg("missing_index_impact", "sum"),
    Missingcount=pd.NamedAgg("missing_index_impact", "count"),
)
```

---

You used

```
_.agg({'missing_index_impact':['sum','count']})
```

but this would give a `MultiIndex` column. Hence, trying to rename using

```
_.rename(columns={'(missing_index_impact, sum)':'MissingSum'})
```

wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes this worked. Great explanation as well thank you! @Ch3steR

Comment: @LeoTorres Glad it was helpful. Added link to the docs you can read more about "named aggregation".